# error is issued Notice: Undefined property on OpenCart 3

Tags: opencart-3

Help solve the problem on OpenCart 3. When opening the product, an error is issued Notice: Undefined property: Proxy::getArticleRelatedByProduct in /home/p/prestig136/storage/modification/system/engine/action.php on line 79.
The code of the file referenced by the error.

```
    /**
 * 
 *
 * @param   object  $registry
 * @param   array   $args
*/  
public function execute($registry, array $args = array()) {
    // Stop any magical methods being called
    if (substr($this->method, 0, 2) == '__') {
        return new \Exception('Error: Calls to magic methods are not allowed!');
    }

    $file  = DIR_APPLICATION . 'controller/' . $this->route . '.php';   
    $class = 'Controller' . preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $this->route);
    
    // Initialize the class
    if (is_file($file)) {
        include_once(modification($file));
    
        $controller = new $class($registry);
    } else {
        return new \Exception('Error: Could not call ' . $this->route . '/' . $this->method . '!');
    }
    
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($class);
    
    if ($reflection->hasMethod($this->method) && $reflection->getMethod($this->method)->getNumberOfRequiredParameters() <= count($args)) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($controller, $this->method), $args);
    } else {
        return new \Exception('Error: Could not call ' . $this->route . '/' . $this->method . '!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You trying to call model function `getArticleRelatedByProduct()` to call model function you need to col model file first for example:

```
$this->load->model('extension/module/your_module');
```

Then call the function

```
$this->model_extension_module_your_module->getArticleRelatedByProduct();
```

Comment: And how to understand what to create in the model?

Comment: in the corresponding model should be: `public function getArticleRelatedByProduct() {
//your code here
}`